# How do I retrieve some input value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Example my temporary input is `1,2,3`

```
<input type="hidden" id="temp" name="temp" value="1,2,3">

var tempvalue = $("#temp").attr("value")
```

With jQuery it's possible to get the number `3` only for `tempvalue`? So `1,2,` will be removed while onclick action.

Comment: I guess you could try javascript string.substring method. But, The value will be always 1,2,3 or in general it is a comma separated value?

Comment: the value is dynamic according to previous `.each()`

Comment: Thanks. So: `(tempvalue.split(","))[2]` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parts = tempvalue.split(',');
var third_value = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var tempvalue = $("#temp").attr("value").split(',')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the whole value and use it as an array OR use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to get the number you want